# Cannot read POST content from Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, post, azure-functions

I´m trying to read the POST content from the azure function. For develop reasons I decide to copy the exact sample from Azure Portal and my code is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage; // Namespace for CloudStorageAccount
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table; // Namespace for Table storage types
using System.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace UnioAzureFunctions.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/telemetria")]
    public class TelemetriaController : ApiController
    {      

    [AllowAnonymous]        
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage request, TraceWriter log)
    {
        try
        {
            // parse query parameter
            string name = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            // Get request body
             string data = await request.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();

            var telemetria = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Telemetria>(data);
            // Set name to query string or body data
           // name = name ?? data?.name;

            //TODO: Usar CloudCOnfigurationManager ou ConfigurationManager normal *
            //// Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
            //CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            //    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

            #region conexão com cloud table storage
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);

            // Create the table client.
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            // Retrieve a reference to the table.
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("telemetria");

            // Create the table if it doesn't exist.
            table.CreateIfNotExists();


            // Create the TableOperation object that inserts the customer entity.
            TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(telemetria);

            // Execute the insert operation.
            table.Execute(insertOperation);


            #endregion

            return name == null
                ? request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

}

public class Telemetria : TableEntity
{
    public Telemetria(string carteira, string crm, string app,
        long idTenant, long idUsuario, string operadora, string action, DateTime dataHora)
    {
        Carteira = carteira;
        Crm = crm;
        App = app;
        IdTenant = IdTenant;
        IdUsuario = IdUsuario;
        Operadora = operadora;
        Action = action;
        DataHora = dataHora;
    }

    public Telemetria()//não retirar - necessário para funcionar o tableEntity
    {

    }
    public string Carteira { get; set; }
    public string Crm { get; set; }
    public string App { get; set; }
    public long IdTenant { get; set; }
    public long IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Operadora { get; set; }

    public string Action { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataHora { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, my goal is to read this POST and Desserialize to my entity called "Telemetria" and save this to a table into my azure storage account. 
I have no idea why I can´t read the content in this line:
`string data = await request.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();` the data is always null and I just don´t know why.
It seems that since this is an azure function I can´t simulate the behaviour as the webapi.

Any help is welcome. Thank´s in advance.

Comment: Since you are deserializing the content as a `string`, why not just use the Content's `ReadAsStringAsync()` method? `string data = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`

Answer (score 0):

> For develop reasons I decide to copy the exact sample from Azure Portal

With [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) Update 3 (v15.3),we could create the **precompiled** Azure azure function and we could debug it locally, more detail info we could refer to this [blog](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Creating-Precompiled-Azure-Functions-with-Visual-Studio-2017).

As  Andrés Nava - .NET mentioned that please have a try to use `string data = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, it should work.